# accessing erc20 token contract from another contract

Tags: solidity

I have a few contracts in one `contract.sol` file.
The first one is a generic ERC-20 contract:

```
contract SimpleToken is IERC20 {

    string public constant name = "SimpleToken";
    string public constant symbol = "SIMP";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_ = 1000;

    using SafeMath for uint256;

   constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function contractAddress() public view returns (address) {
      return address(this);
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The second has a few functions with the intention of calling my SimpleToken:

```
contract SimpleContract is Voting {

    IERC20 public token;

    constructor() {
        token = new NewsToken();
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(tokenOwner);
    }
}
```

When I call balanceOf in the SimpleToken contract, it works as expected (tells me I have 1000 tokens). But when I call the balanceOf function in SimpleContract, it returns 0. I understand they are two separate contracts deployed to different addresses, but aren't they connected through the `token = new NewsToken();`? I want to perform function calls to the token contract in my SimpleContract, but they don't seem to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

When `SimpleContract` is deployed, it has no knowledge of where `NewsToken` is actually deployed. You could easily have a situation where there are multiple `NewsToken` contracts deployed.

You need to change `SimpleContract` constructor to take an address parameter:

```
constructor(address contractAddress) {
    token = SimpleToken(contractAddress)
}
```

When it comes to deployment time, deploy your Token contract, get it's address, then deploy your SimpleContract and pass in that address.